# why php framework include template file use ob_start

Tags: php

I see the framework that company use and CI framework,when include template file ,they use like this

```
ob_start();
include $file;
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $buffer;
```

I want to know just include function file could assign varibles to template file and include,why use ob functions?

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: So they can capture output and assign it to a variable?